# React. Почему нельзя передать пропсы прямо из tsx в jsx замемоизированный компонент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

Дано:

- Есть условный компонент TSXcomponent, который находится в файле с расширением .tsx
- Есть условный компонент JSXcomponent, который находится в файле с расширением .jsx
- JSXcomponent обёрнут в memo
- allowJs в tsconfig включён
- JSXcomponent имеет пропсы и использует их
- TSXcomponent передаёт пропсы в JSXcomponent
- Получаем ошибку:

```
Type '{ someProperty: propertyType }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & object'.
Property 'someProperty' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & object'.
```

Для наглядности:

**JSXcomponent**

```
export const JSXcomponent = memo((props) => {
   return <div>{props.value}</div>
})
```

**TSXcomponent**

```
import { JSXcomponent } from './jsx-component.jsx'

const TSXcomponent: FC = () => {
   const variable = 'value';

   return <JSXcomponent value={variable} />
}
```

И вот здесь уже value подсвечивается тайпскриптом, мол, ошибка.
Если убрать memo обёртку - то ошибки не будет. То есть проблема в типизации memo.

Как я обошёл эту проблему

**Способ 1 (странный):**

```
const TSXcomponent: FC = () => {
   const variable = 'value';

   const props = {
      value: variable
   }

   return <JSXcomponent {...props} />
}
```

**Способ 2 (jsdoc):**

```
/** @type {FC} **/
export const JSXcomponent = memo((props) => {
   return <div>{props.value}</div>
})
```

Вопросы:

- Со вторым способом решения всё понятно. Ts считывает jsdoc и понимает, что же возвращается. Но почему работает первый вариант?
- В чём вообще соль проблемы с 'IntrinsicAttributes & object'

Comment: В первом варианте интерпретатор знает, что в константе props есть свойство value и оно строка, т.к. вы явно объявили их

Comment: Можете попробовать добавить описание типов в jsxcomponent.d.ts